# extraction of grid_index from open3d VoxelGrid is very slow

Tags: python, performance, 3d, gpu, open3d

I'm trying to voxelize an .obj mesh (from blender) and convert it to a numpy array (save it as a .npy or nii.gz as a CT-3D image).

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('path/to/file.obj')
voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(mesh, voxel_size=0.01)
voxels = np.array([voxel.grid_index for voxel in voxel_grid.get_voxels()])

grid_size = voxels.max(axis=0) + 1

voxel_array = np.zeros(grid_size, dtype=np.uint16)
voxel_array[voxels[:, 0], voxels[:, 1], voxels[:, 2]] = 1

np.save('path/to/file_open3d.npy', voxel_array)
```

I have a good GPU so open3d works great with cuda, and voxelization works fast, but I can't find a way to extract all the grid_indexes without a for loop :

`voxels = np.array([voxel.grid_index for voxel in voxel_grid.get_voxels()])`

This takes a lot of time compared to voxelization.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use loop, i found an "solved" issue that recommends loop...: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/1418  Can't help with this more, can only recommend looking for some alternative package. Or as Wobi suggested, go for C++

Answer (score 0):

Currently I work a lot with mesh generation in python. I also have experienced slow speeds when using python to do tasks like for loops over huge amount of data (I did calculations with over 10Mio vertices and later saving them). My fix was to implement these bottleneck functions in C++ and then compile a .so file from my C++ file to then call it in python with the "ctypes" module. Now my calculations are at least 10 times faster. So I suggest you do the same just for you for loop and implement a method to iterate over the loop in C++ and then return the data back to your Python script.

Here is a good starting point, that explains the steps needed to call C++ code in python: [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)